# Different notions of weak head normal form?

Tags: haskell

There are already plenty of questions about weak head normal form etc. and once I read through them I thought I got it. But then I read this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus_definition#Weak_head_normal_form) where WHNF is defined for the lambda calculus as follows:

```
whnf[ (\x.y) z ] = false    (1)
whnf[ \x.(f x) ] = false    (2)
whnf[ x y ] = whnf[ x ]     (3)

in all other cases
whnf[x] = true              (4)
```

I'm fine with clause (1) and (4). However, clause (2) seems wrong to me. According to my understanding, an expression

```
\x.x+1
```

is equivalent to

```
\x.(+) x 1
```

which should be in WHNF since its outermost construct is a lambda abstraction, but according to (2) it's not.

Furthermore, clause (3) seems wrong to me too, since it is of the form of a lambda application.

I'm coming from the Haskell world. Is it possible that there exist different notions of WHNF in the lambda calculus and the Haskell language?

Comment: Isn’t (2) just saying that terms need to be eta-reduced to be in WHNF? Eta reduction being the difference between `\x -> (+) 1 x` and `(+) 1` (the former is not eta-reduced, i.e  it has a redundant lambda).

Comment: yes, I missed the point of eta reduction. Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\x.(+) x 1` is not in the form `\x. f x`, so (2) does not apply and it is in WHNF.

By contrast, `\x.(+) 1 x` *is* in the form `\x. f x` (`f = (+) 1`), so (2) applies and it is not in WHNF.

To be pedantic, here wikipedia is considering beta-eta WHNF. Haskell, like many other languages, does not perform eta-reduction, only obtaining beta WHNF.

Clause (3) is intended to apply to any application `expression1 expression2` who does not match with (1), I think. I am not a fan of the notation used there by wikipedia: usually `x,y,z` stand for variables (only), and `M,N,O` for arbitrary terms.

Still, I can't understand what you mean by "it is of the form of a lambda application".

Comment: Uhh I didn't see the difference between beta-eta WHNF and beta WHNF. Now it makes sense to me.

With "it is of the form of a lambda application" I actually thought that in `x y` the expression `x` may be an arbitrary lambda expression. Thus I got confused by the notation of WikiPedia.

Thanks for clarification!